# sql add user input to existing value

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, psql

I'm using a psql database and the rest is Ruby using Sinatra.
I've got my controllers, my models, my views, etc.

I'm doing a little inventory app and currently I can only update the database with the new quantity in stock via a html form in one of my views.

```
UPDATE products SET (name, quantity) = ('#{@name}', #{@quantity}) WHERE id = #{@id};
```

However, I'd like to be able to put in the amount that was ordered/delivered into a form instead of the new quantity on stock.

I know I can do

```
UPDATE product SET quantity = quantity + 200 WHERE...and so on.
```

but that doesn't take the 200 from the form.

This is the first time I'm asking a question here, so if there is anything missing please let me know and I'll provide you with more info.

Comment: `UPDATE product SET quantity = quantity + #{params[:quanity]} WHERE ...`? This probably requires additional validation, but the core is that.

Answer (score 0):

As mudasobwa mentioned in a comment, you can insert the quantity value in the SQL statement. If you're reading in values from a form (or any other form of user input), I would recommend using parameters in the SQL statement rather than inserting the values directly through string interpolation. This helps prevent some forms of SQL injection by escaping invalid characters.

If you're using the `PG` gem directly to connect to the database, you can use something like:

```
conn = PG.connect(connection_params)
conn.exec("UPDATE products SET quantity = quantity + $1 WHERE id = $2", 
          [params[:quantity], params[:id]])
```

This will insert the quantity and ID values into the `$1` and `$2` placeholders respectively, but it will also ensure that the values don't break or maliciously modify the SQL statement.